# How to insert row data between consecutive dates in HIVE?

Tags: date, hadoop, insert, hive, hiveql

Sample Data:

```
 customer    txn_date    tag
    A           1-Jan-17    1   
    A           2-Jan-17    1 
    A           4-Jan-17    1 
    A           5-Jan-17    0         
    B           3-Jan-17    1
    B           5-Jan-17    0
```

Need to fill every missing txn_date between date range (1-Jan-17 to 5-Jan-2017). Just like below:

Output should be:

```
customer    txn_date    tag
A           1-Jan-17    1   
A           2-Jan-17    1 
A           3-Jan-17    0 (inserted)
A           4-Jan-17    1 
A           5-Jan-17    0  
B           1-Jan-17    0 (inserted)
B           2-Jan-17    0 (inserted)
B           3-Jan-17    1
B           4-Jan-17    0 (inserted)
B           5-Jan-17    0
```

Comment: Is this the format you are actually using for dates?

Comment: Any date format will suffice.

Answer (score 6):

```
select  c.customer
       ,d.txn_date
       ,coalesce(t.tag,0) as tag       

from   (select date_add (from_date,i)   as txn_date

        from   (select  date '2017-01-01'   as from_date
                       ,date '2017-01-05'   as to_date
                ) p

                lateral view 
                posexplode(split(space(datediff(p.to_date,p.from_date)),' ')) pe as i,x
        ) d

        cross join (select  distinct 
                            customer 

                    from    t
                    ) c

        left join   t

        on          t.customer  = c.customer
                and t.txn_date  = d.txn_date
;
```

---

```
c.customer  d.txn_date  tag
A   2017-01-01  1
A   2017-01-02  1
A   2017-01-03  0
A   2017-01-04  1
A   2017-01-05  0
B   2017-01-01  0
B   2017-01-02  0
B   2017-01-03  1
B   2017-01-04  0
B   2017-01-05  0
```

Comment: select  
  c.sub_id
 ,d.txn_dt
 ,coalesce(t.dwe_sms,0) as dwe_sms       
from(
 select 
 cast(date_add(to_date(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(from_date, "ddMMMyyyy"))),i) as date) as txn_dt
from(
 select  
 cast(to_date(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('01JAN2017', "ddMMMyyyy"))) as date) as from_date
 ,cast(to_date(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('31JAN2017', "ddMMMyyyy"))) as date) as to_date
    ) p
lateral view 
posexplode(split(space(datediff(p.to_date,p.from_date)-1),'')) pe as i, x
) d

Comment: This is a tested code and the results in my answer are actual execution results. What issues are you experiencing?

Comment: cross join(
select distinct 
 sub_id
from JBD_DOSSWE_T2_B
) c
left join JBD_DOSSWE_T2_B on t.sub_id  = c.sub_id and t.txn_dt = d.txn_dt

Comment: sorry about the code distortion. Yes the code is ok. When i updated it to include date manipulation that's the time a having issues.

Comment: You don't need to manipulate the `from_date` and `to_date`, maybe  `txn_date`

Comment: Example (replace the hard-coded date): `select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('31JAN2017', "ddMMMyyyy"),'yyyy-MM-dd');`

Answer (score 0):

Just have the delta content i.e the missing data in a file(input.txt) delimited with the same delimiter you have mentioned when you created the table.

Then use the load data command to insert this records into the table.

```
load data local inpath '/tmp/input.txt' into table tablename;
```

Your data wont be in the order you have mentioned , it would get appended to the last. You could retrieve the order by adding order by txn_date in the select query.

Comment: The missing date/s is/are different for every customer. Let's say I have a million customers, the code should know who among them have missing dates and fill this up so that all of them have Jan1-Jan5 txn_dates.